# Create array with non-integer increments

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create time stamp arrays in Swift.

So, say I want to go from 0 to 4 seconds, I can use `Array(0...4)`, which gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

But how can I get `[0.0, 0.5 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]`?

Essentially I want a flexible delta, such as `0.5`, `0.05`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`stride(from:through:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641185-stride):

```
let a = Array(stride(from: 0.0, through: 4.0, by: 0.5))
```

Comment: This is wonderful & works great -- thanks so much Alexander !

Comment: @Saif Also, you can use `stride` directly if all you need to do is iterate the numbers. It'll save you from having to allocate an array

Answer (score 0):

#### An alternative for non-constant increments (even more viable in Swift 3.1)

The `stride(from:through:by:)` functions as covered in [@Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41512917/4573247) is *the* fit for purpose solution where, but for the case where readers of this Q&A wants to construct a sequence (/collection) of *non-constant increments* (in which case the linear-sequence constructing `stride(...)` falls short), I'll also include another alternative.

For such scenarios, the [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence) is a good method of choice; used to construct a lazy sequence that can be repeatedly queried for the next element.

E.g., constructing the first 5 ticks for a log10 scale (`Double` array)

```
let log10Seq = sequence(first: 1.0, next: { 10*$0 })
let arr = Array(log10Seq.prefix(5)) // [1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0]
```

---

Swift 3.1 is intended to be released in the spring of 2017, and with this (among lots of other things) comes the implementation of the following accepted Swift evolution proposal:

- [SE-0045: Add `prefix(while:)` and `drop(while:)` to the stdlib](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0045-scan-takewhile-dropwhile.md)

`prefix(while:)` in combination with `sequence(first:next)` provides a neat tool for generating sequences with everything for simple `next` methods (such as imitating the simple behaviour of `stride(...)`) to more advanced ones. The `stride(...)` example of this question is a good minimal (very simple) example of such usage:

```
/* this we can do already in Swift 3.0 */
let delta = 0.05
let seq = sequence(first: 0.0, next: { $0 + delta})

/* 'prefix(while:)' soon available in Swift 3.1 */
let arr = Array(seq.prefix(while: { $0 <= 4.0 }))
    // [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]

// ...
for elem in sequence(first: 0.0, next: { $0 + delta})
    .prefix(while: { $0 <= 4.0 }) {
        // ...
}
```

Again, not in contest with `stride(...)` in the simple case of this Q, but very viable as soon as the useful but simple applications of `stride(...)` falls short, e.g. for a constructing non-linear sequences.